# Adding a column based on values of other columns

Tags: r, dataframe

The variable `Jaehrlichkeit` is basically a factor with 3 levels: `HQ30`, `HQ100`, `HQ300`. I want R to read `Jaehrlichkeit`. If `Jaehrlichkeit` = `HQ30`, the copy the value from the column `intHQ30` in the correponding row and paste it in the newly created column `Intensitaet`. Repeat this for `HQ100` and `HQ300`.

I was trying to combine the `mutate` function with nested `ifelse` but keep getting errors. Can please someone help me out? or maybe suggest an easier solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `row/column` indexing.  Get the names of the columns that start with 'int' followed by 'HQ' and some numbers (`\\d+`) using `grep`.  Then, get the column index for each row by `match`ing the 'Jaehrlichkeit' with the substring of 'v1', `cbind` with the row sequence and use that to extract the values from the `intHQ` columns and assign it to create the 'Intensitaet'

```
v1 <- grep("^intHQ\\d+", names(sub1), value = TRUE)
sub1$Intensitaet <- sub1[v1][cbind(1:nrow(sub1), 
           match(sub1$Jaehrlichkeit, sub("int", "", v1)))]
```

Comment: many thanks. This does exactly what i needed.  I am fascinated how easy some users solve problems.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to split, and apply, i.e.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$Jaehrlichkeit), function(i) {
                      i$Intensitaet <- i[[grep(i$Jaehrlichkeit[1], names(i))]]; i
                                                              }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `Jaehrlichkeit` is of type factor, you could do this vectorized:

```
r <- sub1[,match(paste0("int", levels(sub1$Jaehrlichkeit)), names(sub1))]
sub1$Intensitaet <- r[cbind(seq(nrow(r)), as.numeric(sub1$Jaehrlichkeit))]
```

- First you get the value of columns `intHQ100`, `intHQ30` and `intHQ300` in your data frame in the order of `levels(sub1$Jaehrlichkeit)`.
- Then you generate the indices and create the `Intensitaet` column.